# Receive data from socket - debug gone and code hangs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, asyncsocket

I followed the example in MSDN about C# socket programming.

```
 private static void StartClient() {
// Connect to a remote device.
try {
// Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
// The name of the
// remote device is "host.contoso.com".
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("host.contoso.com");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

// Create a TCP/IP socket.
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

// Connect to the remote endpoint.
client.BeginConnect( remoteEP,
new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
connectDone.WaitOne();

// Send test data to the remote device.
Send(client,"This is a test<EOF>");
sendDone.WaitOne();

// Receive the response from the remote device.
Receive(client);
receiveDone.WaitOne();

// Write the response to the console.
Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

// Release the socket.
client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
client.Close();
} catch (Exception e) {
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
}
```

I've created a simple test application that works. 
The app sends and receives the response almost instantaneous.

So now the challenge is to implement the solution where the socket connects to an external device that will process the information from the socket and then send back a response. 
At the line "Send test data to the remote device" --> the device receives this information at processes.

The debug keeps on going. The process is still going on in the remote device because I can see the data churning away.

But once it gets to `receiveDone.WaitOne();` the debug is gone and the application hangs.
The problem here is the remote server is still processing. When it is done it is supposed to send back a response. Nothing happens.

Since I'm not that experienced with socket coding, I was wondering if anyone has run into this before. And if yes, how would I go about solving this issues so I can get a response back and the application doesn't hang?

---

Update:

I feel like smacking myself in the head. 
The issue isn't with the WaitOne(). 
The debug is gone from WaitOne() because it's waiting for a response. 
When the response comes, it goes to Receive() which then calls ReceiveCallback().

```
 private void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);

            //THIS IS WHERE THE CODE DOESN'T CONTINUE.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = e.InnerException.ToString();
        }
    }
```

When ReceiveCallback() is complete and it finishes getting all the data - it stops. It doesn't go back to my code where I initiate the sending and receiving of data.

It's supposed to go:
1. Get input request string
2. Pass it to the socket code
3. Socket code sends input request string
4. Socket code receives response string
5. Take the response string and do something with it

So it stops at #4 and ends without completing all the steps. 
Am i missing code for it to continue the flow? Or have I set the process up incorrectly?

Thanks again for the help. 
@John - thanks for updating my title. I'll try to keep the title in mind for the future.

========================================

UPDATE 2:
If I change the code and do not use the Receive() as it is in the MSDN sample, [MSDN sample link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx) and do something like:

```
            var response = client.Receive(buffer);

            var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
```

This would work and everything continues. I need to make sure that the response isn't cut off though. But then that would defeat the purpose of it by async client correct?
Hmm....
thanks again for everyone's input.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it after seeing how I went wrong. 
I didn't check for the end response. I assumed that the end of the buffer transmission would set off the method that would return the response.

Thanks to everyone for your help. I couldn't have come to the solution  without your help. 
cheers!